# Conditional filtering with left join

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have a `books` , `users` and a `books_users` table.

Now, i want to get a book that is managed by me (user_id = 3) and other user(user_id = 18):

```
SELECT *
FROM books as Book
LEFT JOIN books_users as BookUser
    ON BookUser.book_id = Book.id
WHERE
    Book.user_count = 2 AND
    BookUser.user_id = 3 AND
    BookUser.user_id = 18
```

Problem:
as the left join splits the result of books in rows, it doesn't give a row with the two users...

Comment: How can `BookUser.user_id` be both 3 and 18?

Comment: @Andrew That's just an example of how he wants it to work.  I believe he's looking for a `Book` that has exactly 2 `BookUser`s with `user_id`s of `3` and `18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to join to the BookUser table twice to get both conditions and use DISTINCT to get the book once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Book.*
FROM books as Book
LEFT JOIN books_users as BookUser1
    ON BookUser.book_id = Book.id
LEFT JOIN books_users as BookUser2
    ON BookUser.book_id = Book.id
WHERE
    Book.user_count = 2 AND
    BookUser1.user_id = 3 AND
    BookUser2.user_id = 18
```

Comment: I don't understand the need of left join and distinct?

Comment: @NitinMidha The `LEFT JOIN` is debatable, but the `DISTINCT` makes it return only one row per book instead of two.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking that it would still have two rows, but that's the original problem and we're past that at this point.  The `DISTINCT` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM books as B
 INNER JOIN books_users as BU1
    ON BU1.book_id = B.id
 INNER JOIN books_users as BU2
    ON BU2.book_id = B.id
 WHERE B.user_count = 2
   AND BU1.user_id = 3
   AND BU2.user_id = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about user_count column.

This gives books which are used either by 3 or 18

```
SELECT *
FROM books as Book
INNER JOIN books_users as BookUser
    ON BookUser.book_id = Book.id
WHERE
    Book.user_count = 2 AND
    BookUser.user_id IN  (3,18)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM books as Book
INNER JOIN books_users as BookUser
    ON BookUser.book_id = Book.id
WHERE
    Book.user_count = 2 AND
    (BookUser.user_id = 3 OR BookUser.user_id = 18)
```

Edit: This gives books used by both 3 and 18.

```
SELECT book.*
FROM books as Book
INNER JOIN books_users as BookUser1
    ON BookUser1.book_id = Book.id
INNER JOIN books_users as BookUser2
    ON BookUser2.book_id = Book.id
WHERE
    Book.user_count = 2 AND
    BookUser1.user_id = 3 AND
    BookUser2.user_id = 18
```

Comment: Your queries would return incorrect results.  Example: a book a `user_id`s `3` and `5`.  It has `3 OR 18` and user count of `2`.

Comment: @G-Nugget, I was confused by one variable having two values. But re-read the question and comments. Updated the answer.